# DMC Floss list library

Tags: xml

I am trying to create a program for my wife to manage her [cross stitch floss](http://www.dmc.com/majic/pageServer/0r0100001c/en/Threads.html). I would like to use a library that contains all of the numbers and their associated colors however I have not been able to find a XML file to parse or library to load anywhere, free or paid.
Does any craft enthusiasts know where I could get a XML or library that would contain all of the floss numbers and their colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this file. I hope this will help.
https://github.com/kohsuke/dmc-cross-stitch/blob/master/src/main/resources/dmc-floss.csv

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if this is what you are asking for but you may find it helpful all the same. Log on to http://yarntree.com/075dmc.htm Best of luck.